# Drawing line from fixed point 50px towards mouse position Java

Tags: java, graphics, trigonometry

I am trying to draw a line which is 50px in length from a fixed point to a point based on the position of the mouse but I am terrible at trigonometry. 
I have been stuck on this all day and still have no idea how to do it.
the four variables used are:

```
startX; //X position of fixed point
startY; //Y position of fixed point
mouseX; //X position of mouse
mouseY; //Y position of mouse
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to make a [Unit Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) (a vector with length 1) in the direction of the mouse cursor to the point. Then you multiply the unit vector by 50 and you've got a vector of length 50 in that direction.

So you first get the vector from the fixed point to the mouse cursor:

```
float dirX = mouseX - startX;
float dirY = mouseY - startY;
```

Then your normalize this vector (make it's length 1)

```
float dirLen = sqrt(dirX * dirX + dirY * dirY); // The length of dir
dirX = dirX / dirLen;
dirY = dirY / dirLen;
```

Now we multiply the normalized vector by 50 and  we've got a vector of length 50 in the direction we want.

```
float lineX = dirX_normalized * 50;
float lineY = dirY_normalized * 50;
```

Now we can draw our line

```
g.drawLine(startX, startY, startX + lineX, startY + lineY);
```

Comment: Nice, no trig required either. Just a scale. :-)

Comment: Glad you did that... I was about to type in an answer using sin & cos

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the [AWT `Graphics` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html), you could do this:

```
double angle=Math.atan2(mouseY-startY, mouseX-startX);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawLine(startX, startY,
    Math.floor(startX+Math.cos(angle)*50),
    Math.floor(startY+Math.sin(angle)*50));
```

Comment: This is probably slower than David's answer.